# C# - Reading data from CSV file and show them in DataGridView

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvData.DataSource = LoadCSV(@"C:\working\Summary.csv");
    }
    
    public List<Product> LoadCSV(string csvFile)
    {
        var query = from line in File.ReadAllLines(csvFile)
                    let data = line.Split(',')
                    select new Product
                    {
                        A = data[0],
                        B = data[1]
                    };
                    
        return query.ToList();
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am a beginner who started using C# from last week for work.

`.csv` file containing simple numbers is read, but it is containing spaces which result in an error

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException

[image]

Comment: The only place the posted code could throw the `IndexOutOfRangeException` is on the line… `B = data[1]` … this line of code ASSUMES there are at least two (2) items in `data.` It is wise to check if there are enough items in the collection, “before” you try to use them. The error indicates that somewhere in the CSV file, there is a line that does not have any commas (,) in that line. This line is going to cause your code to the throw the exception you see. I suggest you check what is returned from… `let data = line.Split(',')`.

Comment: _csv containing spaces results in an error_ __Spaces__? Really?? - Also: What does the image tell us??? - Also: The code is not just unchecked, it also assumes there are no commas inside of string fields.

Comment: thank you. I was able to figure out what was the problem.

Comment: The problem was that there was a line with only one cell, and there was no comma in the line. I'll find another code and use it.

Comment: @TaW OP mentioned "_I am a beginner who started using C# from last week for work._"

Comment: @ati : So? I only pointed out what issues his post has. At least one of which still is in your answer; but knowing the data and their rules is not for us to know.. - Maybe he meant 'lines' where he wrote 'spaces'. All the more important to learn to use the correct terms. - I tired to help, not to put him down. Shouldn't we all always assume good intentions, my friend?

Comment: @TaW My apologies, if my comment implies my assumption of any bad intentions. Peace  :)

Comment: Yes, all is well :-)

Answer (score 1):

Following is a simplified, non-`LINQ` version of the `LoadCSV()` method which might help you understand your scenario better in code. The method -

1. creates a `Product` only if the line has any value
2. creates the `Product` with only property `A`
3. sets a value for property `B` only if the second value is available

```cs
public List<Product> LoadCSV(string csvFile)
{
    // create an empty list
    var list = new List<Product>();

    // read all the lines
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(csvFile);
    
    // do some processing for each line
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        // split line based on comma, only if line is not an empty string
        // if line is an empty string, skip processing
        var data = line.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);      
        if (data.Length == 0)
            continue;

        // we skipped empty lines, so data has at least one element
        // we can safely create a Product with the first element for property A
        var product = new Product { A = data[0] };
        
        // if data has more than one element, then we have a second element
        // we can safely assign the second element to property B 
        if (data.Length > 1)
        {
            product.B = data[1];
        }
        
        // add the product to list
        list.Add(product);
    }
    return list;
}
```